# Writing to a file I get unauthorized access error.How can I do it?

Tags: c#, windows-7, permissions

Despite numerous post on the web I cannot find an answer to my problem.
I am writing an application that writes csv files to folders.Users should be able to pick a directory.
I am developing in windows 7 using vs2010 running my app in Admin Mode.Regardless of all this I still get the "Unauthorized access exception" when I do

```
   var path=@"c:\" or c:\MyFolder
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendLine("Test");
   var myFile=sb.ToString();
   using (var writer=new StreamWriter(path))
     {
        writer.Write(myFile);
     }
```

Am I missing something?
I have feeling that in window7 you can only write to designated folders.Is this what's happening?

any suggestions?

EDITED

I have created few folders under "C:\MyFolder\"

I am not using any credentials eg windows impersonation etc..

It does write if it writes to the bin\debug\ of my class library. but not to any designated folder.

Comment: It could be the path you're using. Even in Admin Mode, some directories are still protected. Make the path your C drive root. See if that works.

Comment: Can you give us examples for 'path' and 'myfile'?

Comment: does you app use windows impersonation?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer some of the questions

Comment: If you try to have the app write the file to your desktop, does that work?

Comment: I am assuming you are running the app as your account, so under that account, try using another app to write to the directory to eliminate permissions as the issue. Can you open Excel and create a new file in that directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your code snippet the real code causing the problem?

On the face of it, you are trying to stream the text "Test" into a **directory** on the file system, not trying to write a file. (`path` is just assigned to `@"C:\"`). I'm not surprised that you get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Assign the full path of the file you want to write into your `path` variable, and I imagine you'll succeed.

Comment: @ChisDickson.the were 2 things in my real code I was writing to a folder I didnt have access too and when I did the noddy test i forgot to combine the path with name of the file .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app with "Run as Administrator". The comments above will probably also steer you in the right direction. You should definitely pick a directory that your windows users has access to edit.

Comment: "Run as Admin" should not be needed to write to a non-system directory. If that were the case, every app that writes to a custom folder (c:\my_temp_folder) would need "Run as Admin" set, and that is not the case.

Comment: I agree that the app should be writing to user directories unless the requirements state that the file must go in the path he is setting up. The OP will have far fewer problems down the line using user directories (permissions problems, pissed off sys admins because you are writing to a weird path, etc.).